# Creating visual force sidebar force service console

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, service-cloud-console

I am new to visual force and I am trying to add a custom side bar to the service console.

I want to update this side bar here and I know you can't remove some of the fields that are on the standard object.
[image]

So I have created a visual force page. Here is that code

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Case Details">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!$ObjectType.Case.FieldSets.Case_Console_Fields}" var="f">
            <apex:column value="{!f}">
                <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!f.Label}">
                <apex:facet name="header">Label</apex:facet>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!f.Type}" >
                <apex:facet name="header">Data Type</apex:facet>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

But when I preview the page I get this:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Which has no data and when I add it to the console layout I get this:
[image]

Comment: Can you add 2nd image correctly?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can't add a page to the console, only a component instead. See the Service cloud Console developer' Guide for more. The 'undefined' that's displayed should be giving you a clue that things are inherited from the title bar, just like with a component.

Comment: Thanks Santanu, I will take a look at that. I thought I need the page for the component I will take a look at the guide.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify the 'Available for Salesforce mobile apps and Lightning Pages' flag (available when editing the VisualForce Page) is set ON? see here - https://www.screencast.com/t/uzFeeSDQVm

I have the same 'standardController' page which is showing just fine as a 'Custom Console Component'.

Comment: I tested your code in my sandbox, and was able to get the Customer Console Component alright (see here https://www.screencast.com/t/SDtFnwwdv). I suppose you might find an indicative error in the logs, to further troubleshoot this. Before doing so, verify that the VIsualForce Page has the appropriate Profiles associated (in the VisaulForce Pages list, hit 'security' next to your VF Page, and select the profiles to 'Enable Profile Access for Visualforce Page').

Comment: iDog, I do have the profiles enabled correctly but I still am getting the error.

Comment: As I was able to receive the Custom Console Component in my SandBox with your code, I assume this should work. You'll have to further troubleshoot this with your 'debug logs' to reach the root cause.